# Expanding IP address number

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, routing

At the moment I'm managing a little network (7 hosts) linked to the outside world through a normal ADSL connection.
This little network is inside a consulting room in which works 4 medic + 2 secretaries, recently my region decided to give internet connection for free to all the consulting rooms they can reach.

Now, my problem is that the region gave me 4 ip adresses but I have 7 hosts, what is the best way to connect all of them to the outside using all the 4 ip adresses?  A load-balanced proxy?  Routing 2 network?

Comment: You need to better specify your requirements. Does any single person or device require a public IP for any given reason? Does single person or device require that others connect to the machine remotely? Do you really require the use of all 4 IPs, or will just one suffice if all devices have internet access? Without knowing exactly what you will be running on that little network of yours, it is hard to give a network topology recommendation. RedGrittyBrick's answer is a good basic setup, and probably will suffice, but it would help us give you better information if you were more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a router that supports [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (NAT) - almost all do. The usual arrangement is to use an address range [reserved for private use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) such as 192.168.0.* internally (either static or DHCP) and have the router translate that to one (or more) external IP-addresses.

Most [SOHO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_office/home_office) routers do this out of the box.